# I have a linker issue for node-gyp cross compile

Tags: linker, arm, node-gyp, cc

I want to do a cross compile nodejs C++ addon (node-gyp).
env set like

```
export AR=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-ar
export CC=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
export CXX=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++
export LINK=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

this is my binding.gyp

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'binding',
      'sources': [ 'binding.cc' ],
      'includes': ['../common.gypi'],
      "cflags" : ['-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon --sysroot=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi'],
    }
  ]
}
```

Command is 'node-gyp --arch=arm configure build'
I think compiling has passed but linker show errors like this.

```
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/binding.node
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot open crti.o: No such file or directory
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot open crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot open crtendS.o: No such file or directory
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot open crtn.o: No such file or directory
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot find -lstdc++
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot find -lm
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot find -lgcc_s
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot find -lpthread
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot find -lc
/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: error: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone have similar issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by myself.
this is whole binding.gyp file.

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'binding',
      'sources': [ 'binding.cc' ],
      'includes': ['../common.gypi'],
      "cflags" : ['-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon --sysroot=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi'],
      'link_settings': {"libraries": [ "-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon --sysroot=/2nd-hdd/home/pkang/sdk/tm2sdk/sysroots/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi"], },
    }
  ]
}
```